# How to mimic Audacity's "truncate silence" with ffmpeg "silenceremove" filter

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to remove completely silence parts from wav files with ffmpeg.

Input wav can be like :
[image]

I am using the following ffmpeg command to remove silence part `ffmpeg -i input.wav -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=0.2:stop_threshold=-45dB output.wav` because I understand from the [doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove) that it will remove all silence parts longer than 0.2 s (silence being below -45dB).

But I get that [image] where silence part has only been reduced to around 0.1 wheras I want it to be 0 (no remaining silence).

In Audacity I will use "truncate audio" filter and choose the above parameters to detect silence and in the action part I will choose to truncate to 0: [image].

This will yield to what I want (ie an audio with no silence part remaining):
[image]

Searching on [the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/1374480/how-can-i-automatically-cut-all-silence-0db-from-mp3-without-reencoding) only lead me to what I already do.

So how can I reproduce the output I get from Audacity "Truncate Silence" filter with ffmpeg and remove all silence parts from audio ?

*Edit: The output from silencedetect filter is correct:* `ffmpeg -i input.wav -af silencedetect=0.2:n=-45dB -f null -` detects exactly what audacity detects.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the equivalent command to AUdacity's truncate silence behaviour is the following (in bold what is added):

ffmpeg -i input.wav -af silenceremove=**start_periods=1**:stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=0.2:**start_threshold=-45dB**:stop_threshold=-45dB output.wav

I am not sure why adding those 2 parameters leads to the expected behaviour but it works although for some files silenceremove can remove more parts than Audacity / silencedetect detect.